# Trying to title case all words in string

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to title case a string using the String.prototype function syntax. For some reason I am getting: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

```
    String.prototype.toJadenCase = function (str) {
    str.split(' ')
    .map(w => w[0].toUpperCase() + w.substr(1).toLowerCase())
    .join(' ')
    };

    var str = "How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real";

    console.log(str.toJadenCase())
```

Comment: use `this` not str param.  and you didn't return a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `this` to refer to the current object.  Also need to return a value.

```
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function () {
return this.split(' ')
.map(w => w[0].toUpperCase() + w.substr(1).toLowerCase())
.join(' ')
};
```